# How to take array as an input in android?

Tags: java, android

Actually I am designing an android application in which I would be taking array as an input by using `EditText`.  so the thing is I am trying a lot by I am not getting how to do it so. Can anyone help me please.
I don't have a proper code so I am not attaching that but please help me with your code.

How can I take input as an array using `EditText` in android.
I want to insert n elements by `EditText` and than want to convert them in a single array.
like if I give input 1 and 2 and 3 and 4. than I can have a array like `a[4] = {1,2,3,4}`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the user guidelines on how to ask a good question before posting a question (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Thank You

Comment: When user enters, how you wanna separate each input in editText ? ",", Button clicks or something else?

Comment: The idea is , i want to enter numbers and they should store in an array. after this i would be having an **arr[]** so i can implement my scheduling @tahsinRupam

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code to convert String to array:

```
EditText ed = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
String text = ed.getText().toString();
int arr[] = new int[text.length()/2];//Assuming no spaces and user is using one comma between numbers
    int i=0;
    while(text!=null && text.length()>0) {
        arr[i] = Integer.parseInt(text.substring(0,1));
        text = text.substring(text.indexOf(",")+1);
        i++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can type your input and use a character as delimiter. 
Here is an example using `","` as delimeter.

```
    EditText eText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
    String input = eText.getText().toString();
    //split your input using ","
    String[] valuesArray =  input.split(",");
    // now you got a String[] with your values to work with. 
    //If you had input 1,2,3,4 your array is like : {"1","2","3","4"}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can have a text field that keeps taking an element one at a time until the user click on stop.
So you would have one text field and 2 buttons
one button would just add an element to the array(say add to array button), and the other element would be used to denote that the user has finished entering all elements.

so the user would enter an element, click on add to array button, then the the field gets cleared, so that the user can enter the next element. and he can keep doing this until he clicks on "done" button.

On the backend instead of an array, you can have an ArrayList so that you can keep calling list.add(element) every time the add to array button is clicked.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>;
onAddToArrayButtonClick(View v){
list.add(editText.getText().toString();
editText.getText().clear(); //this clears the edit text
}
```

If you want to take the input of the array in one go you can use "," as a delimeter and then call string.split(",");

Something like:

```
onAddToArrayButtonClick(View v){
String[] array = editText.getText().toString().trim().split(","); /*for a user input of 1,2,3,4 split will return a string array = {"1","2","3","4"} */
}
```

Comment: how to print this array? can we use a textView to print array ? i have tried many times to print it . But its showing error .                                                `public void add(View v){   //add is a button
    EditText ed = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.bt);
    TextView tv111 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
    String[] array = ed.getText().toString().trim().split(",");
    tv111.append(array); 
}`

Comment: Well youll want to do is frist convert the array to a string:
that can be done using this:
`String[] arr = {"a","b","c"};
String s = Arrays.toString(arr); /* this will convert arr to a string like "[a,b,c]" */
  s = s.substring(1,a.length()-1); /*this is to remove the the square brackets from start and end */
  System.out.println(s);`

Once you have done that you can set the textView using

`tv111.setText(a);`